# How can I see the balance history of one bank account on Mint?

Tags: mint.com

One can see the total "net worth", which is summed over all linked bank accounts. How can I see the balance history of *one* bank account on Mint?

Comment: My fault for misreading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KRayner1](https://www.reddit.com/user/KRayner1) [pointed](https://redd.it/ob09oe) me to the solution:

> On the website, go to [trends](https://mint.intuit.com/trend.event)/graphs/assets over time. Select the required account and time periods from the drop down boxes down by the actual graph. I don’t believe you can do this on the apps. You have to go to the actual website.